# How to merge more than 10 dta files at once using merge 1:1 command?

Tags: sorting, merge, stata

I am trying to `merge` more than 10 dta files with same unique identifier `id` in Stata. I have tried using the following code, but it shows error `_merge already defined` r(110). I think it is due to creation of variable `_merge` after the first two file merges. Is there a better  work around for this and get all files merged at once?

```
local files : dir "E:\Research\stata12" files "*.dta"
foreach file in `files' {
merge 1:1 id using `file' 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See  `help merge` for the background. By default, `merge` creates the new variable `_merge` as a report on the success (or failure) of the command (NB not function; in Stata function is not a synonym for command).

It follows that

EITHER

1. You need to specify a different variable name with the `generate()` option.

OR

2. You need to `drop` or `rename` the `_merge` variable otherwise.

In either case, it is a very good idea to look carefully at `_merge` at each stage to see if results are as you expect. `tabulate _merge` followed if necessary by a `list` or `edit` is usually sufficient.

Further, forcing a series of `merge`s is efficient coding if and only if you are certain that the `merge`s will be unproblematic. I tend to `merge` one by one, slowly but surely.